# Atmospheric attenuation of a DVB-T2 signal terrestric transmission and the influence of weather

Tags: attenuation

A DVB-T2 signal is transmitted over a fixed distance using three frequencies: 538, 578, and 642 MHz.
The TV channels transmitted with the 538 MHz carrier are very sensitive to rain, but the two other carriers are not affected by weather.

I found published attenuation data only for frequencies above 1 GHz. Is there any published data for frequencies between 500 and 650 MHz?